# code for login form in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm still learning my way around in CodeIgniter.

I'd like to create a login form in my codeigniter application.
My view section is below:

```
<html>
  <head>    
    <title>Jotorres Login Screen | Welcome </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='login_form'>
      <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>Login/process" method='post' name='process' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>User Login</h2>
        <br />  
        <?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?>   
        <label for='username'>Username</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' size='25' /><br />
        <label for='password'>Password</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' size='25' /><br />                            
        <input type='Submit' value='Login' />            
     </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Controller section:

```
<?php

  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  /* Author: Jorge Torres
  * Description: Login controller class
  */
  {
    class Login extends CI_Controller{

      function __construct(){
          parent::__construct();
      }


      public function index($msg = NULL){
          // Load our view to be displayed
          // to the user
          $data['msg'] = $msg;
          $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
      }


      public function process(){
          // Load the model
          $this->load->model('login_model');
          // Validate the user can login
          $result = $this->login_model->validate();
          // Now we verify the result
          if(! $result){
              // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
              $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
              $this->index($msg);
          }else{
              // If user did validate, 
              // Send them to members area
              redirect('Home');
          }        
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Error Message:

> The requested URL /afi/Login/process was not found on this server.

How can I resolve this error?

Model section:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/* Author: Jorge Torres
 * Description: Login model class
 */
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validate(){
        // grab user input
        $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
        $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

        // Prep the query
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);

        // Run the query
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        // Let's check if there are any results
        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            // If there is a user, then create session data
            $row = $query->row();
            $data = array(
                    'userid' => $row->userid,
                    'fname' => $row->fname,
                    'lname' => $row->lname,
                    'username' => $row->username,
                    'validated' => true
                    );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
        }
        // If the previous process did not validate
        // then return false.
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post your question and code properly.

Comment: In your controller's section there is an extra `{ }` tag (maybe you just pasted it wrong). Possible problem, that your .htaccess file is wrong, or you didn't declare your base_url (in config.php), or something else in your codeigniter's config. Your code (Jorge Torres's code) seems to be good (except the annoying `enter code here` lines).

Comment: i have declared base_url...still same error

Comment: When did you get this error message? After the post? Please let us know the details of your error. we can't help you if we don't know anything about your environment. Like I said: this code seems to be right, so the problem will be in your configuration. Your base_url is declared. Is your base_url `http://url.com/afi` ? Do you have an `/afi` directory on your webserver?

Comment: yes../afi is there on my webserver..

Comment: Error while executing this code is given below:Not Found

The requested URL /afi/Login/process was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$query->num_rows` with `$query->num_rows()` in your model and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

try use site_url().
change :

> `<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>Login/process" method='post' name='process' enctype="multipart/form-data">`

to :

> `<form action="<?php echo site_url('Login/process');?>" method='post' name='process' enctype="multipart/form-data">`

`base_url` produce :

> http://localhost/codeigniter/

while `site_url` produce :

> http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php

Answer (score 0):

try this 
 `<?php echo form_open('Login/process')?>`
its best way to resolve your problem